# Flask REST API very slow on simple endpoint

Tags: flask

I'm using a Flask REST API for my application and I've noticed that when I send requests from outside my own network, it's sometimes very, very slow. Most calls get completed within 150ms, but some take 8 seconds. The database connection is to a MySQL database using DBUtils.PersistentDB

The code for the endpoint:

```
@app.route("/name", methods=["POST"])
@jwt_refresh_token_required
def get_name_and_company():
    user = get_jwt_identity()
    response_object = server_functions.get_name_and_company(user)
    return response_object
```

The function it uses:

```
def get_name_and_company(user):
    sql = "SELECT fysios.firstname, fysios.lastname, companies.name FROM 
fysios " +\
        "INNER JOIN companies ON fysios.companyID = companies.id WHERE fysios.email = %s"
    cursor = flask_server.get_db().cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, user)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    first_name = data[0]['firstname']
    last_name = data[0]['lastname']
    company = data[0]['name']
    response_object = name_and_company(first_name, last_name, company)
    return make_response(jsonify(response_object)), 200
```

Here are the timestamps on the Flask server (it is the internal dev server, but I am running it with threaded=True):

```
[08/Mar/2019 22:16:54] "OPTIONS /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[08/Mar/2019 22:16:55] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[08/Mar/2019 22:16:55] "OPTIONS /clients HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[08/Mar/2019 22:16:55] "OPTIONS /verifyLogin HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[08/Mar/2019 22:16:55] "POST /clients HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[08/Mar/2019 22:16:57] "POST /verifyLogin HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[08/Mar/2019 22:16:57] "OPTIONS /name HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[08/Mar/2019 22:16:58] "POST /clients HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[08/Mar/2019 22:17:05] "POST /name HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

As you can see, /name takes a total of 8 seconds and I can't find out why. This call to /name is just an example, it can happen on any of the calls. Is there a way to find out where the Flask application is actually stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying to AWS Beanstalk solved the problem. I don't know if the limitations of the build-in dev server is to blame, but that's what did it for me.